# Login in cakephp 3.4 is not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i'm making a online test web application, these are the controllers

- Faculties
- Students
- Tests
- Notes
- Questions
- Answers
- TestQuestions
- StudentResults
- StudentsTests

> Note : students and faculties both have different logins

I'm trying to login in Faculties Controller,
i have load Auth component in App controller,

When I'm trying to login, it shows an error "username or password is incorrect"

This is the App controller

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'loginAction'=> [
                    'controller'=>'Faculties',
                    'action'=> 'login',
                ],
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'userModel' => 'Faculties',
                        'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'],
                    ]
                ],
                'loginRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Faculties',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ]
            ]);
```

This is the login function in Faculties controller

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            debug($this->request->getData());
            debug($this->Auth->identify());
            $faculty = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($faculty)
            {
                $this->Auth-setUser($faculty);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect');
        }
    }
```

view of login

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

faculties schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`faculties` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `profile_pic` VARBINARY(8000) NULL COMMENT '',
  `mobile_no` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `college` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '',
  `department` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '',
  `subjects` TEXT NULL COMMENT '',
  `created` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  `modified` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

please help whats wrong in the code

Comment: what is your `faculties` database schema ?

Comment: i have added the schema, please help

Comment: do you encrypt your password? if you encrypt it then `password VARCHAR(45) ` length `45` is not enough increase it and try again  by registering

Comment: Yes sir, I'm using password hashing.

Comment: Right sir, I'm using password hashing.

Answer (score 0):

- Verify the name of each fields (email or mail/ password or passwd)
- Verify that you add inside src/Model/Entity/Faculty.php "[function _setPassword](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/fr/controllers/components/authentication.html#hachage-des-mots-de-passe)"
- debug the $faculty value maybe you have a problem with your validation (src/Model/Table/FacultyTable.php)